# Photoshop CC brush-specific dynamics

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, brush-dynamics

In Photoshop I made a pencil type brush for sketching using the brush settings using pen pressure to control scattering, line thickness and opacity.

However, when I change to a different brush e.g. hard edge, large diameter for shading, the brush settings stay so all brushes now have those scattering, thickness and opacity settings.

[image: brush presets, applied to all brushes]

How can I make these settings *only* apply to my pencil-type brush so I can use other brushes without re-creating my settings every time I want to use another brush?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **Brush Presets**.

Set your brush up how you'd like...

Then click the `New` icon on the **Brush Presets Panel**. A new preset will be created with all your settings.

[image]

If you want to change brushes you can do 1 of 2 things:

1. Choose a *different* preset and the defined settings for *that* preset will be loaded. Or....
2. Adjust the options in the **Brush Panel** for a new brush.

To go back to your "Pencil" brush, at any time, merely click the **Preset** in the Brush Presets panel you created and all the settings you saved will be loaded.

---

Brush presets hold brush settings similar to how the `Styles` panel holds Layer Style presets, or Character/Paragraph styles hold type presets.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you define the options of a brush and you want to keep it, you must save it.

- Open on the drop-down **Brush Library** at the top left of the screen and click on the save icon.

[image: Brush Library]

Once saved, go back to the **Brush Panel** options menu and select **Clear Brush Controls**

[image: Brush Panel Menu]